# Setting variable inside table update statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

`TempTable` has columns `RunningTotal` and `ClientCount`, we also have `@RunningTotal` variable declared and set to 0.

Can someone please explain what does this line do ?

```
UPDATE Temptable 
SET @RunningTotal = RunningTotal = @RunningTotal + ClientCount
```

Comment: i think update the variable (@)RunningTotal and the field of the table together with this value (@)RunningTotal + ClientCount

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never seen this construct before, but it seems to work like this.
It fills column `RunningTotal` with a cumulative total of `ClientCount`.

Say we start with a table with just `ClientCount` filled in:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Temptable (ClientCount int, RunningTotal int)
INSERT INTO Temptable (ClientCount) VALUES (5), (4), (6), (2)
SELECT * FROM Temptable

ClientCount RunningTotal
----------- ------------
5           NULL
4           NULL
6           NULL
2           NULL
```

And then run the update statement:

```
DECLARE @RunningTotal int = 0
UPDATE Temptable SET @RunningTotal = RunningTotal = @RunningTotal + ClientCount
SELECT * FROM Temptable

ClientCount RunningTotal
----------- ------------
5           5
4           9
6           15
2           17
```

As you can see, each value of `RunningTotal` is the sum of all `ClientCount` values from the current and any preceding records.

The downside is, you have no control in which order the records are processed. Which makes me wonder whether this is a recommended approach in a production environment.

Please check here for a deeper discussion:
[Calculate a Running Total in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860966/calculate-a-running-total-in-sql-server)